# Poor UDP broadcast performance to multiple processes on same PC

Tags: sockets, udp, winsock, broadcast, multihomed

We have an application that broadcasts data using UDP from a server system to client applications running on multiple Windows XP PC's. This is on a LAN, typically Gigabit. This has been running fine for some years.

We now have a requirement to have two (or more) of the client applications running on each quad core PC, with each instance of the application receiving the broadcast data. The method I have used to implement this is to give each client PC multiple IP addresses. Each client app then connects to the server using the same port number but on a different IP. This works functionally but the performance for some reason is very poor. My data transfer rate is cut by around a factor of 10!

To get multiple IP addresses I have tried both using two NIC adapters and assigning multiple IP addresses to a single NIC in the advanced TCP/IP network properties. Both methods seem to give similarly poor performance. I also tried using several different manufacturers NICs but that didn't help either.

One thing I did notice is that the data seems to come over more fragmented. With just a single client on a PC if I send 20kBytes of data to the client it almost always receives it all in one chunk. But with two clients running the data seems to mostly come over in blocks the size of a frame (1500 bytes) so my code has to iterate around more times. But I wouldn't expect this on its own to cause such a dramatic performance hit.

So I guess my question is does any one know why the performance is so much slower and if anything can be done to speed it up?

I know I could re-design things so that the server only sends data to one client per PC, and that client could then mirror the data on to the other clients on the same PC. But that is a major redesign and re-coding effort so I'd like to keep that as a last resort.

Comment: Why broadcast rather than multicast? And why did you need the weird hack with the IP addresses at all?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating one IP address for each client, try using setsockopt() to enable the SO_REUSEADDR option for each of your sockets. This will allow all of your clients to bind to the same port on the same host address and receive the broadcast data. Should be easier to manage than the multiple NIC/IP address approach.

SO_REUSEADDR will allow broadcast and multicast sockets to share the same port and address. For more info see:
[SO_REUSEADDR and UDP behavior in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077887/so-reuseaddr-and-udp-behavior-in-windows)
and
[Uses of SO_REUSEADDR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577885/uses-of-so-reuseaddr)

Comment: Thanks. I had previously tried this but the application just hung. I did not write the application but I believe there is some other network traffic using the same IP address that gets messed up when sharing. I will look into it further to see if I can get it to work.